# Rails web app: Rack app error handling request { GET /packs/js/application-682c14949987e19a8380.js }

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, webpack, puma

When I load the home view (or any view) on my local version of a Rails 6 app, which I'm running with webpack-dev-server through localhost, the page will load, but but not the javascript as I continue to get the following internal server error when webpack calls for application.js in my app/javascript/packs directory:

```
    2020-07-28 18:04:57 -0500: HTTP parse error, malformed request ():
    #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
    
    --- 
    2020-07-28 18:04:57 -0500: Rack app error handling request { GET /packs/js/application-682c14949987e19a8380.js }
    
    #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: wrong version number>
```

followed by some more extraneous/vague information.
When I run bin/webpack-dev-server, everything (I'm assuming) goes smoothly as so:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at https://localhost:3000/

ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /packs/

ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/gabe/domus/public/packs

ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 6c3a88060d923134f5c3

Version: webpack 4.44.0

Time: 1399ms

Built at: 07/28/2020 5:51:22 PM

                                    Asset       Size       Chunks                         Chunk Names

   js/application-682c14949987e19a8380.js    508 KiB  application  [emitted] [immutable]  application

js/application-682c14949987e19a8380.js.map    572 KiB  application  [emitted] [dev]        application

                            manifest.json  364 bytes               [emitted]

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

In my application.html.slim file I call the application.js file with javascript_pack_tag:

```
html
  head
    title Domus
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag

    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'

  body
    = yield
```

And my webpacker.yml file looks like so:

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  resolved_paths: []

  cache_manifest: false

  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  check_yarn_integrity: true

  dev_server:
    https: true
    host: localhost
    port: 3000
    public: localhost:3000
    hmr: false
    inline: false
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'
```

I'm not too sure what else to try. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe the issue may be that webpack didn't create a manifest.json file within the packs directory.

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by running `bin/webpack-dev-server` first and then `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your rails server and webpack-dev-server in different ports, Rails usually runs in port 3000 while webpacker by default uses 3035, so in webpacker.yml make sure to use a different port:

```yaml
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
```

You might also have to disable `https` in webpacker.yml depending on your setup.

Comment: Actually I have enabled https with `dev_server:
    https: true` and it worked xD